# Alert doesn't appear after POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I get an alert when the select menu has "Please select your country" and I click the checkout button but when I select Canada on it for example and then select "Please select your country" again and press checkout I don't get any alert. I want the alert to appear at all times if the select menu has "Please select your country" and the user presses checkout.

**JQuery:**

```
      jQuery(function($){
        $('#checkForm').submit(function() {
          var checkShipping = $("#shipping").val();
          if(checkShipping == 'none'){
            alert('Please select a shipping option before proceeding');
            return false;
          }
        });
    });
```

**HTML part:**

```
echo "<form id='checkForm' method='post' action='checkout.php'>\n";
echo "<select id='shipping' name='shipping'>\n";
echo "<option id='none' value='none'" . ($this->shippingarea == 'none' ? ' selected="selected"':'') . ">Please select your country</option>\n";
echo "<option id='1' value='1'" . ($this->shippingarea == 1 ? ' selected="selected"':'') . ">United States</option>\n";
echo "<option id='2' value='2'" . ($this->shippingarea == 2 ? ' selected="selected"':'') . ">Canada</option>\n";
echo "</select>\n";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Update' />\n";
echo "</form>\n";
```

**Demo: (You have to add an item into the cart first)**
[here](http://asiraj.com/checkout.php)

**My php code:**
[link](http://pastie.org/pastes/9240682/text?key=apq3flskghvt7am5dn8nxa)

Comment: Done any basic debugging yourself, e.g. `alert(checkShipping)` to see what your submit handler's finding?

Comment: Please don't use alert for debugging :-)

Comment: @Sam That's not true. The value of a select is the value of the selected option.

Comment: @Sam The question you linked to is about getting the _text_ of the selected option, not the _value_.

Comment: Well it works fine on page load and when debugging with the alert.. the alert says "none" which is fine but when I select Canada and update shipping then select "Please select your country" again and press checkout. No alert of any kind

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected @Barmar..just JSFiddled it :P

Comment: It works fine for me. I select Canada, select Please select, click on Checkout, and I get the alert.

Comment: You have to press Update Shipping then checkout... sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: Then the problem probably has something to do with what Update Shipping does.

Comment: @Ballbin He didn't post the complete PHP code, he's not showing the `echo "` at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Sorry, It was my fault on that I will update it! :) But a down vote is a bit harsh as I spent quit a lot of time on it.

Comment: You are posting a question posing a problem that does not exist, wasting everybody's time. That's why I downvoted.

Comment: How does the problem not exist? I switch option to Canada and press Update Shipping. Then when I press checkout... I don't have any alerts popping

Comment: It only happens for you, not us, therefore it doesn't exist within the code you have provided. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It has to be with my PHP code that I also provided because the problem is that after I POST the shipping value. I don't get any alert

Comment: `($this->shippingarea == none ? ' selected="selected"':'')` you're missing quotes around `none`...

Comment: I put quotes around it but still no luck. Will update the question with the quotes

Comment: I also noticed in your php (pastie.org link) You have the `script` tag around your `script` as `<script="text/javascript">` you might to change that to `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the AJAX `success` function in jcart.js contains:

```
container.html(response);
```

This replaces all the elements in the `jcart` DIV. So your `$("#checkForm").submit()` binding is lost, because the element it was bound to has been replaced. You need to use event delegation:

```
$("#jcart").on("submit", "#checkForm", function() {
    ...
});
```

Since you're using a version of jQuery that predates `on()`, you have to use `delegate`, which takes its arguments in a different order:

```
$("#jcart").delegate("#checkForm", "submit", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Still not working. It doesn't even give an alert when I directly click checkout now without doing anything else

Comment: Not sure why. There's an issue with delegating the "submit" event in IE, but jQuery works around it starting in version 1.4, and you're using 1.5 (why such an old version?).

Comment: Can you provide a link to the version of your page that uses this?

Comment: I am going to temporally update my script with yours @Barmar so please check it out now.

Comment: actually it says TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
 

$("#jcart").on("submit", "#checkForm", function() {

Comment: Oops, `on` was added in jQuery 1.7. I've rewritten the answer to use `delegate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54817/discussion-between-iheartbreakz-and-barmar).